# Interactive scheduled tasks without logging in

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a scheduled task that runs periodically and causes PDFs to be printed. The process is relatively simple and works fine on Windows Server 2003. The task must run whether or not the user is logged in. We're having trouble getting this working on Windows Server 2008 R2.

The task works if I specify that it should run only when the user is logged in. It does not work if I specify that it must run whether or not the user is logged in. Presumably this is because interactive applications simply cannot run from Session 0 in Server 2008. I'm not sure that it's possible to overcome this problem.

**So, I'm willing to resort to running the task only when the user is logged in**; let's call the user Interactive. I could set the system to automatically log in as Interactive on startup. However, I'd rather not let someone with physical access to the server have such easy access to the system. A perfectly acceptable solution is one that leaves the Interactive user logged in, but their session locked.

Is it possible to cause Windows Server 2008 to create an interactive session for a certain user without actually causing the system to display that desktop to someone with physical access (and who does not have the password)?

Comment: Related: [Windows 7: Automatically login and lock](http://superuser.com/questions/352616/windows-7-automatially-login-and-lock)