# Windows 10 disconnects network when locking pc

Tags: networking, windows-10

Since a few weeks it seems that my laptop, after being locked for a few minutes, will kill the network connection. Every time I return to my it after it being locked for a while, I see apps having to reconnect, or tasks that have failed because lack of network connectivity. It happens on both wired and wireless connections.

Is there a way to disable this behavior? I've looked in Windows power settings, and NIC settings, but haven't found anything.

I'm working on a Surface Pro 3 with Windows 10 version 1703 build 15063.413

Comment: How long have you been away from the device? Could it be that it switches to standby/hibernation?

Comment: Have you checked wireless network Adapter in power setting. You can also find the setting related to your issue in Wireless or Ethernet Adapter Configurations. i.e Power Management

Comment: Standby/hibernation is set to 'Never'. Also the setting to disconnect network when in standby is set to 'Never'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop Windows 10 going to sleep after locking with Win+L key](https://superuser.com/questions/1153162/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-going-to-sleep-after-locking-with-winl-key)

Comment: Not sure if the last mentioned setting corresponds to the [toggle](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/surface-it-pro-blog/surface-power-management-with-modern-standby-in-windows-10/ba-p/328897) between disconnected and connected (modern) standby... Anyway few weeks from July 2017 seems to match a [certain](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/surface-pro-3-update-history-78dc8c2a-97ba-fd87-f24f-ed76e8a66a38) undefined update to improve sleep battery life.

Answer (score 6):

This may be because of a "System unattended sleep timeout" setting that is normally hidden, and that causes a locked computer to sleep even when the "Sleep" setting is set to "Never".

See [this answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1186786/950740).

Per the link above, the System Unattended Sleep Timeout setting is made available in your power settings if you set the DWORD attribute of the following registry key to "2":

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0
```