# Windows 10 Laptop disconnects from WiFi when waking from lock

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, drivers

My experiences are hyper-similar to this guy: [Windows 10 disconnects network when locking pc](https://superuser.com/questions/1226268/windows-10-disconnects-network-when-locking-pc).

My `Acer E5-575-52jf` laptop running Windows 10 build `1703` with the `Atheros QCA9377` wireless chipset spontaneously disconnects from every wireless network I have tried using when waking up from me locking it by closing the screen.

The network connection icon in the notification center shows the status as disconnected, and it has to reconnect, usually within a few seconds, but that is enough to have disrupted every pending network action I have going at the time.

I have already tried a few things to "repair" the issue:

1. Unchecking the power management setting within the Network Adapter Properties dialog
2. Install a newer WiFi driver from the [Acer Website](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6752?b=1) and "look for a newer driver online" from Device Manager (*To no avail, as the newest device driver is already installed*)

I am at a loss for what I can try to do next. Please share any ideas you may have. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @El8tedN8te Not a pastebin, but I hope this works: https://gist.github.com/neilbalch/fb34815ea759859881a6c7dd5bfb378d

Comment: My account is the only one on the system. Yep. See https://gist.github.com/neilbalch/d4267f216988cbd2609f2a1b06344456 for full output.

Comment: Done. Do you think that will solve the issue?

Comment: It somewhat doubt it it'll change anything. If not, can we look at `netsh wlan show settings`

Comment: I will try this "fix" out for a couple days and get back to you.

Comment: Go to Adapter Properties (or Configure) →Advanced. Disable Ad Hoc QoS mode. Set U-APSD support to disabled. Set Roaming Aggressiveness to Low (or better Disabled). Then try `netsh winsock reset`

Comment: I do not have either of the two options, and I can only set Roaming Aggressiveness to `Lowest`, which I did. I will get back to you in a couple days, @El8tedN8te

Comment: The options I was able to reduce settings for did improve the probability of a dropped connection but failed to make the connection never drop.