# Task Scheduler has been set to lock computer after logon. how to disable this? as the computer instantly locks after logon

Tags: shutdown, lock

I created a task schedule following this [How to LOCK computer after 'x' amount of time right after log on](https://superuser.com/questions/1728435/how-to-lock-computer-after-x-amount-of-time-right-after-log-on)

to lock on logon. but i didnt put a delay. now i cant login at all, as the computer instantly gets locked after login.

any idea how i can solve this?

Comment: Did you try running Windows in safe mode?

Comment: @Destroy666 , how do you run in safe mode when you can't access the desktop to access it?  Microsoft messed safemode up bigtime.  I just tried doing it on my box from the login screen (using shift->restart) and it doesn't work on my machine from the login screen, only from the desktop.

Comment: yeah cant even test safe mode as the "spam F8 button on boot to go to safe mode" no longer work

Comment: `F8` method doesn't work by default in Windows 10. There was a way to restart while holding Shift key on the login screen though that opens boot menu. Not sure if it still works. Did you check?

Comment: thanks! that got it into safe mode. it now says "task scheduuler cannot run in safe mode"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @destroy666 comment and this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/deleted-task-reappears-each-day/ec17b2e8-9a5a-42aa-a568-605bcac1e15a

to fix

1. hold shift while pressing RESTART on the login screen
2. enter safe mode
3. go to windows/system32/tasks and regedit  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks
4. delete the problematic task
5. reboot to normal windows