# How to stop Windows 10 from moving windows when after unlocked?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a Dell XPS 13 Laptop with Windows 10 to the side of my external LG 27" screen. The external screen is plugged in to the DisplayPort socket of a Dell TB16 Dock. Whenever my laptop is unlocked, I have to wait several seconds because it is moving all my windows to the main screen (the laptop screen). When there are lots of windows open I have to move them all back to where they were.

**None of my screens are disconnected by me when this happens.**

It's starting to get really annoying. It didn't used to do this when the laptop was positioned below the external screen.

Comment: The usual workaround is to make the screen wake first, so the computer sees it sooner.

Comment: By default in locked state Windows sets all monitors to stand-by mode after a view seconds. Looks like your monitor is disconnected by this stand-by mode. You can try to increase the lock screen stand-by time-out and see if this increases the time where the windows are not moved to the main screen: https://superuser.com/a/1186786/62676

Comment: I thought it was fixed @Robert but that article doesn't seem to have done it. I set the value to 2 hours and left my PC for one hour, unlocked and everything was moved to main screen.