# Windows 10 PC locks after Screensaver wait time, even though it is disabled in settings and gpo

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, screensaver

**Problem solved by Ramhound**

All PCs in my domain lock after the wait time in the screensaver settings.
If I set the wait time to 1 minute the PC locks after 1 minute.

The PC locks after 1 minute. The screensaver is disabled.

I don't want either the screen locking nor a screensaver. The computer should stay on and be operable.

I have disabled screensavers locally and with my GPO. I am in control of the GPOs.

**Screensaver settings locally:**

Screensaver None

On resume, display logon screen Disabled

**Screensaver settings GPO:**

Enable screen saver Disabled

Prevent changing screen saver Enabled

**Other GPO settings**

I disabled the "enforce user logon restrictions" Kerberos policy.

Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit is not defined. I will test if setting it to 0 will fix my problem. It fixed my problem.

Where do I find password protect the screen saver and screen saver timeout?

**The GPO power plan is as follows:**

| When computer is: | Plugged in | Running on batteries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Require a password on wakeup: | No | No |
| Turn off hard disk after: | Never | Never |
| Sleep after: | Never | Never |
| Allow hybrid sleep: | Off | Off |
| Hibernate after: | Never | Never |
| Lid close action: | Sleep | Sleep |
| Power button action: | Shutdown | Shutdown |
| Start menu power button: | Hibernate | Hibernate |
| Link State Power Management: | Moderate power savings | Maximum power savings |
| Minimum processor state: | After 5 minutes | After 5 minutes |
| Maximum processor state: | After 100 minutes | After 100 minutes |
| Turn off display after: | Never | Never |
| Adaptive display: | On | On |
| Critical battery action: | Do nothing | Shutdown |
| Low battery level: | After 10 minutes | After 10 minutes |
| Critical battery level: | After 5 minutes | After 5 minutes |
| Low battery notification: | Off | Off |
| Low battery action: | Do nothing | Do nothing |

Are there GPO settings that interfere with this?
What should I change?

Comment: I am confused;  Is your screensaver turning on (after 1 minute) or the user account locking after 1 minute of inactivity?  What is `Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit` configured to? What is `password protect the screen saver and screen saver timeout.` set to?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.  If you want the machine to never automatically lock, set the inactivity limit to, zero (0).

Comment: Are you in control of the Domain Policies or are you just wanting something different for yourself?

Comment: Try the solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/1153162/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-going-to-sleep-after-locking-with-winl-key/1186786#1186786